# How to check if a value exists in a select box using vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a function that accepts an argument of `check` that will loop through select box options and values and check to see if the value exists or not. I have it working (kinda) but it only checks the first option. If you run `checkOption('red)`, you get an alert that Option Exists. However, if you run `checkOption('green')`, nothing happens.

I'm doing something simple here, but I can't figure it out. Thanks for any and all help.

### Working CodePen:

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Sackadelic/pen/BajKzbP)

### JavaScript:

```
let selectBox = document.querySelector("select");
let options = selectBox.querySelectorAll("option");

function checkOption(check) {
    options.forEach((o) => {
        if (o.value === check) {
            return true; // returns undefined either way.
        }
    });
}
}
```

Edit: I am now able to get `console.log()` to print to the console, but I'm trying to return either `True` or `False`. How would I amend the above function to return `True` or `False`? So far, this only returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop through the `options` in your function. You can also shorten by using `forEach` on the collection:

```js
function checkOption(check) {
    options.forEach( o => {
        if( o.value === check) {
            alert(`${check} is available`);
        }
    });
}
```

You could condense even more by using the array `filter()` function as well. You just need to make treat the options `NodeList` as an array but sticking it through the `Array.from()` method first:

```js
function checkOption(check) {
   if( Array.from(options).filter( o => o.value === check ).length )
      alert(`${check} is available`);
}
```

or even shorter, let the function returns true or false to indicate the presence of the given option value.

```js
function checkOption(check) {
   return Array.from(options).filter( o => o.value === check ).length > 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I much prefer the `forEach` syntax over the for loop. What is the benefit of using a filter over the `forEach` loop?

Comment: In this case, it's so trivial, it's mostly providing more concise code. However, in other cases, the `forEach` _does_ something on each iteration, while the `filter` returns a filtered copy of the array based on the function you provide.

Comment: Thanks for all of these options! Great reference.

Comment: Hey @JakeParis, why am I getting a TypeError when running the `options.filter` function?  I'm getting `TypeError: options.filter is not a function`. Does `filter` need anything else to run?

Comment: Oh, yeah, because options is actually a `NodeList`, not a true `Array`. `forEach` _will_ work, but filter needs an extra little piece. Sorry, I've updated the code examples. now.

Comment: Am I daft, or is 'options.forEach( o =>' in above example missing the closing ")" somewhere?

Comment: Thanks @Cristofayre you're right about the missing `)` -- fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `options.length` in your loop. Besides that, it is good practice to define variables before using them. Your return statement should also be called immediately after a match is found to avoid unnecessary iterations, so you better include it in your if statement.

```
let selectBox = document.querySelector("select");
let options = selectBox.querySelectorAll("option");

function checkOption(check) {
  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; ++i) {
    if (selectBox.options[i].value === check) {
      alert(`${check} is available`);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```